How to install Outline Client (VPN)
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"

For Linux it is supplied only in AppImage, if I run it on raspberry pi I get an error
./Outline-Client.AppImage 
-bash: ./Outline-Client.AppImage: cannot run binary file: Executable file format error

There may be unofficial clients for connection.

At a guess (as I don't know what the error message actually says) I would say that the appimage is not for Arm but for Intel processors...

@Dirk Sorry, here is the translation of the error "cannot run binary file: Executable file format error". Yeah, I also think it's a CPU architecture issue. But I also hope there is some hack to fix it (or an unofficial client).

@ykoavlil: when a program is build for a certain CPU architecture, there is no (easy) fix or hack to convert is to another architecture. Unfortunately, the download page for the client is poorly documented and doesn't say anything about CPU architectures for Linux.
A possible solution may be to build the client from scratch on the Raspi, as the project seems to be Open Source (Link to GitHub). However, if this is really possible for the Raspi 4 you need to try.

@noisefloor I'm not sure if my skills are enough for this, but thanks for the tip. Actually, I meant more that maybe there are unofficial clients that support this protocol.
